# Iterating over (selected) features by the same id

Tags: arcpy, cursor, iteration

I have a feature class `Test_NearestNeighbor_Code`. This feature class has 7373 polygon features and a column/ field called `osm_id`. I want to do a calculation with all features that have the same `osm_id`. How can I do this in arcpy in an iterative way over all features (without using the ModelBuilder)?

Calculate Field code works, but loop with `SearchCursor` doesn't, any suggestions for improvement?

Attached the Attribute Table of the feature class `Test_NearestNeigbour_Code`.

[image]

````
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Test_NearestNeighbour_Code", ["osm_id"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        arcpy.management.CalculateField("Test_NearestNeighbour_Code", "Dispersitätsmaß", "nn_output[1]", "PYTHON3", 'nn_output = arcpy.stats.AverageNearestNeighbor("Test_NearestNeighbour_Code", "EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE", "NO_REPORT", None)', "DOUBLE", "NO_ENFORCE_DOMAINS")```
````

Comment: Title of your post is misleading.

Comment: to determine a spatial dispersion measure that indicates whether sub-areas in a feeder catchment area are more spatially dispersed or clustered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing your features have unique id field called "UNIQ_ID" and osm_id is integer field the script below should work.

INPUT:

[image]

Script:

```
import arcpy
inLayer = "all_points"
aSet = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(inLayer,"OSM_ID"))
tempFc = "in_memory/selected"
aDict={}
for item in aSet:
    arcpy.AddMessage('Processing item %s' %item)
    arcpy.analysis.Select(inLayer, tempFc, '"osm_id" =%i'%item) #modify query if osm_id is a string
    result = arcpy.stats.AverageNearestNeighbor(tempFc)[1]
    tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(tempFc,"UNIQ_ID")
    for row in tbl:aDict[row[0]]=result #memorize result in dictionary
arcpy.AddMessage('Results transfer...')
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inLayer,("UNIQ_ID","z_score")) as cursor:
    for oid,z in cursor:cursor.updateRow((oid,aDict[oid]))
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Hi FelixIP,  thank you very much for your very quick reply. I've tried your code several times and I don't understand why some of the polygon (in your code the point) feature with the same osm_id have different z_score values (in my column "Dispersitätsmaß"). Attached is the table and my code for it. Do you have an idea what it could be? I had to convert "osm_id" to the "Double" data type because the numbers of the osm_id were larger than the maximum of the "Long Integer" data type.

Comment: Your polygons identifiers are not unique.

Comment: okay, with the "osm_id_double" as "UNIQID", it works.

Comment: Is it possible to add the condition that it should only execute it if at least two polygon features have been selected after the command “arcpy. analysis. Select”, maybe in the command “result = arcpy. stats. AverageNearestNeighbor (tempFc) [1]” ? Because the Nearest-Neighbor-analysis need two features

Comment: Use getCount after Select. If it is less than 2, continue. Read first how getCount works. Modify cursor.updateRow((oid,aDict[oid])) to cursor.updateRow((oid,aDict.get([oid],-1)))

Comment: i try this in the code below, but it don´t work perfectly, any suggestions to improve this?

Comment: If count <2:continue  or simply clean up data before running your code.

Answer (score 0):

with > 1, it works with "cursor.updateRow((oid,aDict[oid]))", but with a result in the column "Dispersitätsmaß" of features, which getCount <=1 . For them, it should be no result (), because the calculation should not be carried out.  Any suggestions to improve this?

with "cursor.updateRow((oid,aDict.get([oid],-1)))" below, i´ll get this error message

```
import numpy
inLayer = "Test_NearestNeighbour_Code"
aSet = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(inLayer,"osm_id_zahl_double"))
tempFc = "selected"
aDict={}
for item in aSet:
    arcpy.AddMessage('Processing item %s' %item)
    arcpy.analysis.Select(inLayer, tempFc, '"osm_id_zahl_double" =%i'%item) 
    if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(tempFc).getOutput(0)) > 1 :
        result = arcpy.stats.AverageNearestNeighbor(tempFc)[1]
    tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(tempFc,"osm_id_zahl_double")
    for row in tbl:aDict[row[0]]=result
arcpy.AddMessage('Results transfer...')
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inLayer,("osm_id_zahl_double","Dispersitätsmaß")) as cursor:
    for oid,z in cursor:cursor.updateRow((oid,aDict.get([oid],-1)))

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [7]:
Line 15:    for oid,z in cursor:cursor.updateRow((oid,aDict.get([oid],-1)))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).