# Tools that can be used to show whether the point features are scattered or compact

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.8, compactness

I am using ArcMap 10.8. For the shapefile of hospitals, I want to show that they are either scattered or congested within a given area.

Is there any tool I can use for that?

I am very new to this.

Comment: Show as a map or like a analysis/measurement?

Comment: Check and try this https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-mapping-clusters-toolset.htm

Comment: Use average nearest neighbor e.g.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426189/iterating-over-selected-features-by-the-same-id/426197#426197

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of situation where a heatmap can provide an elegant solution. In ArcMap, the tool to use to create a heatmap from points is called "Kernel density". Please search for this tool in the ArcToolbox and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a clustering algorithm and see the area of the cluster as the result of your question. For example, using k-nearest neighbors, your clusters will get smaller in the area's hospitals are getting dense and bigger if there are not many.